# CentOS 6 Static IP Address

Tags: networking, centos, ip

I've just assigned my CentOS machine with a static IP address using the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 which has the following lines and seems to be working

```
#eth0 config

DEVICE="eth0"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=*hardware address here*
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
NAME="System eth0"
IPADDR=10.0.0.66
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

when i use ifconfig I see that ip address is 10.0.0.66, however when I try to assign a gateway with /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=centosVM
GATEWAY=10.0.0.2
```

It doesn't seem to be working, when I use route -n I see that the gateway is 10.0.0.0

How do I set the gateway to work like my static IP?

*UPDATE*

I've just found that if I run dhclient it works. When I check the /etc/resolv.conf it has the nameserver 10.0.0.2 which I want.

I don't know why this fixes it but is there a way that I don't have to run dhclient every time? It doesn't seem right it should have the nameserver in the resolv.conf on boot?

Comment: Off topic: The commands `ifconfig` and `route` are being replaced by the `ip` command, i.e. use `ip addr` to view your IP address and `ip route` to view your routes (see [ip(8)](http://man.cx/ip%288%29)).

Comment: That is off topic but still helpful to know, thanks

Comment: A assue you have already restarted your network using `service network restart` after changing the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file, right?

Comment: Yes, I even restarted the machine to make extra sure

Comment: When you state "gateway" I assume you mean the default gateway (i.e. the gateway of 0.0.0.0/0), right?

Comment: One more: Do you use NetworkManager to setup your network? If yes: you have listed `MM_CONTROLLED=yes` instead of `NM_...`, maybe a typo in your post or an error in your file.

Comment: Yeah the MM was a typo, I was hoping by stating gateway I could set the gateway I want to use which is my router 10.0.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no the solution to your problem but a workaround:

Add the gateway to your `ifcfg-eth0` file instead of the `network` file:

```
#eth0 config

DEVICE="eth0"
MM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=*hardware address here*
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
NAME="System eth0"
IPADDR=10.0.0.66
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.0.0.2
```